# I'm having issues accessing data after fetch

Tags: reactjs, arrays, api, object

I fetched data from an API and I get this :
An array of arrays containing objects and properties containing the details of songs.

[image]

The issue is when i try to access the uri property, I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')" with the code below :

```
 const songTitleEl = chartData.map(data =>(
    <ChartSongs key={data.key} audio={data?.hub?.actions[1]?.uri}/>
  ))
```

It should be working perfectly but it isn't and for the life of me I can't figure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actions could be null. Need the `?` to check if index exists

```
<ChartSongs key={data.key} audio={data?.hub?.actions?.[1]?.uri}/>
```